# Powershell process, set location

Tags: git, powershell

Hi I am having a problem i am using power shell to commit changes and send result back to c# library, so simple commands work I am getting call back but now as i do pull and push i need to monitor this process so I've implemented start process

for example

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "git.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "commit -m \`"{tag}\`""

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()

$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

Write-Output "Output: " + $stdout
Write-Output "Error: " + $stderr
Write-Output "Error Code: " + $p.ExitCode
```

It looks like it will work bit i need to set pointer to git repository as process lunches in git directory and output looks like:

> Output: 
>   Output: 
>   fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
>   exit code: 
>   128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx):

> WorkingDirectory
>
> When the `UseShellExecute` property is **false**, gets or sets the working directory for the process to be started. When `UseShellExecute` is **true**, gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be started.

```
...
$pinfo.UseShellExecute  = $false
$pinfo.WorkingDirectory = 'C:\some\folder'
...
```